# My site does not get aproved by Adsense. Issues: Unacceptable site content

Tags: google-adsense, blogger

I've submited my website to adsense and after 5 days i got this email:

> Hello,
>
> As mentioned in our welcome email, we continue to review your AdSense
>   application once AdSense code is placed on your sites. As a result of
>   this review, we have disapproved your account for the following
>   violation(s).
>
> Issues:
>
> - Unacceptable site content
>
> ---
>
> Further detail:
>
> Unacceptable site content: Your website contains content that we do
>   not allow at this time. Please review our policies
>   (https://www.google.com/adsense/policies) for a complete list of site
>   content not allowed on webpages.
>
> ---
>
> To update and resubmit your application, please visit
>   http://www.google.com/adsense and sign in using the email address and
>   password you submitted with your application. Our specialists will
>   review your account for compliance with our program policies, so
>   please make sure to resolve all of the issues listed above before
>   resubmitting.
>
> For more information, visit our Help Center:
>   http://www.google.com/adsense/support/as or search the AdSense Help
>   Forum, where a community of publishers shares AdSense best practices:
>   http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense. Representatives of
>   Google AdSense also participate in discussions.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google AdSense Team

Unacceptable site content, what? My blog is hosted on blogspot: ...
and i don't really understand why it is not approved.

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance...